# Finding the basis and dimension of kerT and imT for a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:V\to U$ be a linear map.
>
> $$V=\Bbb R_3[x] \\U=\mathcal M_{2\times2}(\Bbb R) \\ 
> T(\mathcal P(x))=
>      \begin{pmatrix}
>          \mathcal P(0) &\mathcal P(1)\\
>         \mathcal P(2) & \mathcal P(0)\\
>         \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Find the basis and dimension of $\text{ker}(T)$ and $\text{im}(T)$ for the linear map and determine if it's an injection or surjection.

Well I first of all tried to show that the kernel is equal the zero vector, in this case the zero matrix: $\mathbf O_{2\times 2}$ but because of the constant in the polynomials they will never equal zero.

Please share you thoughts on how to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is ${\Bbb R}_3[X]$? Polynomials of degree $\leq3$?

Comment: @AndreaMori yeah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $p\in \ker(T)$ iff $p(0) = p(1)=p(2) 0$, and so $p$ is of the form
$$
p(x) = ax(x-1)(x-2)
$$
So, $\text{dim}(\ker(T)) = 1$.

Now, given any matrix of the form
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & \beta  \\
\gamma & \alpha
\end{pmatrix}
$$
we can find a $p \in \mathbb{R}_3[x]$ such that $T(p) = A$. So we just need to count the number of possible such matrices. Now note that all such matrices can be written as 
$$
A = \alpha \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} + \beta \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} + \gamma \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and so $\text{dim}(\text{Im}(T))=3$

Comment: How did you know that form ? The dimension of kerT is 2 probably because the basis can be expressed with two polynomials ?

Comment: Also, I understand why p(0)=0 but why also p(1)=0 ? p(1) could be equal $x^3$ for example or just 1.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. Have edited now.

Comment: Can you explain how you found $p(x) = ax(x-1)(x-2)$ ?